# Code doesn't work as expected. VBA code to copy values from one sheet to another if condition met

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I am writing a VBA code to copy values from one sheet to another if the values in column B of the Source sheet are bigger or equal to 10.
I am able to copy the values from the Source sheet to the Target sheet. However, the values copied are wrong.

I have tried changing the condition (values bigger than 10) to see what the output would be. The values are not as expected.

```
Sub findValues()

Dim c As Range
Dim b As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target


Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Source2")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Code Trial2")

b = 2
For Each c In Source.Range("B2:B:20")

If c.Value >= 10 Then

Source.Cells(b, "A").Copy
Target.Cells(b, "A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Source.Cells(b, "B").Copy
Target.Cells(b, "B").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

b = b + 1
End If

Next c

End Sub
```

The Source Sheet contains the following:
Val    Number
A        1
B        2
C        3
D        10
E        12
F        13

I expect the output to be: 10, 12, 13

However, in the Target sheet I get: 1, 2, 3
[Actual Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iousy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Option Explicit
Sub findValues()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet


    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Source2")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Code Trial2")

    b = 2
    For Each c In Source.Range("B2:B20")
        If c.Value >= 10 Then
            Target.Cells(b, "A").Value = c.Offset(0, -1).Value
            Target.Cells(b, "B").Value = c.Value
            b = b + 1
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: You were not taking the C.Value, instead you were picking b, which means the first row to copy was the 5th and you were taking the 2nd. My code will copy correctly what you need.

Comment: Glad it helped. Please consider to mark this as the answer so someone else can find it.